# How can I test two attributes in jsp using c:if tag?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I want to check two attributes sent from server if they are empty or not in jsp using jstl tag c:if . For example I can use to check if error is empty : `<c:if test="${not empty error}"></c:if>` Like this , I want to check two objects error and logout at once to make a div if either of them is empty. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AND operator && or OR operator ||

```
<c:if test="${not empty first && not empty second}"></c:if>
<c:if test="${not empty first || not empty second}"></c:if>
```

If you want them to be empty

```
<c:if test="${empty first && empty second}"></c:if>
<c:if test="${empty first || empty second}"></c:if>
```